# is this a good way to maintain a temporary variable that a method need as an instance variables?

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list

i created a Node class and a LinkedList class:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_node = Node(0)
        self.start_node = self.last_node
        
    def add(self, item):
        new_node = Node(item)
        new_node.next = None

        self.last_node.next = new_node
        self.last_node = new_node
        
        return new_node
```

i want to implement a method to return the length of the linkedlist with recursion.
so i added a new instance variable (i) that maintain current node.
this is final code with len function:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_node = Node(0)
        self.start_node = self.last_node
        self.i = self.start_node
    def add(self, item):
        new_node = Node(item)
        new_node.next = None

        self.last_node.next = new_node
        self.last_node = new_node
        
        return new_node

    def len(self):
        if self.i.next == None:
            return 0
        self.i = self.i.next
        return 1 + self.len()
```

```
l = LinkedList()
head = l.add(1.5)
l.add("3hh")
l.add(5)
l.len()//result is 3
```

is this(save it as instance variable) the best way to maintain a temporary variable that a function need?

Comment: Just as a note you can make your class work with the python length function by adding the method def __len__(self):
        return self.length_function(). Then you can do len(l) rather than l.len()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is not the best way to do it at all because if I call `len` twice on the same list, I'll get two different answers. Not only that, but your original implementation gives the wrong answer since your `__init__` method creates a list with 1 element rather than the empty list (so your test case list actually has a length of 4). The correct thing to do is as follows:

```py
def len(self):
    def node_len(node):
        return 0 if node is None else 1 + node_len(node.next)
    return node_len(self.start_node)
```

This reflects the general principle that if you need some extra information, you should pass the extra information as an input to a function. In this case, we pass the extra information which you store in `self.i` as an input to our helper function, which allows us to calculate the length of a list without mutating it.

Comment: wow,know i see a new area in programming. thank you.  this type of thing (like helper function) is design pattern concepts? can you introduce a book ?

Comment: @usf I'm glad you found this helpful! There is a general coding pattern of passing data into functions - I don't know if I'd call it a design pattern though. If you want to learn more about this kind of thing, I'd recommend you look into functional programming. I don't know of any good Python books, but there's always the classic SICP if you're willing to learn Scheme and tackle some challenging material. If you want to be really hardcore about it, you could try to learn Haskell (but I don't know any great books for that).

Answer (score 0):

A dummy node is often used to simplify the logic of implementing a linked list, as it ensures that the linked list always consists of a `Node` instance, rather than using `None` to indicate an empty list. The "data" in the dummy node is available for arbitrary use, such as storing the length of the list.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_node = self.head = Node(0)
        
        
    def add(self, item):
        new_node = Node(item)
        new_node.next = None

        self.last_node.next = new_node
        self.head.item += 1

    def len(self):
        return self.head.item
```

A `remove` or `delete` method would likewise decrement `self.head.item`.